# For what integer values $a$ does the system of congruences have *at least one solution*?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

For every fixed integer **a** we consider the following system of congruences:

$$ax \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$$

$$x \equiv a \pmod{13}$$

If for example $a=0$, it's easy to see that the system does not have any solutions. The question is, **for what integer values $a$ does the system have at least one solution?**

Here comes my answer to the question:

---

The first equation has a solution **if and only if** $gcd(a,12)|1$. The only divisors that divide $1$ are ${-1,1}$. Therefore $a$ and $12$ must be **co-prime** due to the fact that $gcd(a,12)$ must be $1$ or $-1$ in order to divide $1$.

Knowing that $a$ is **co-prime** with $12$, we can use **Euler's Phi Function**

$$\phi(N) = | \{1 \leq a < n : gcd(a,N)=1\}|$$

to find the possible values of $a$.

$$\phi(12) = |\{1,5,7,11\}|=4$$

With this new information regarding what possible values $a$ can attain. It is clear that the second equation has at least one solution for every allowed $a$.

$a=1 \rightarrow x=1$ solves the system.

$a=5 \rightarrow x=5$ solves the system.

$a=7 \rightarrow x=7$ solves the system.

$a=11 \rightarrow x=11$ solves the system.

So the answer to the question is:

**The system has at least one solution when $gcd(a,12)=1$.**

---

Is my answer/reasoning correct?

---

**EDIT:** Changed **The system has at least one solution when $a \in \phi(12)$.** to **The system has at least one solution when $gcd(a,12)=1$.**

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, $\phi(n)$ is only used to refer to a [number, not a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). So rather than saying $a \in \phi(12)$, you should say $\gcd(a,12) = 1$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ah, yes of course. My mistake! Good catch.

Comment: Otherwise, yes: your answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, it follows from the Bezout criterion for existence of inverse (dupe1) and then by CRT (dupe2),. since the moduli are coprime, i.e. apply CRT to $\,x\equiv a^{-1}\pmod{12}, x\equiv a\pmod{13}\ \ $